# access to variable and work with getter and setter returns always (null)

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I've a native class named Cargo in my Phonegap iOS App which just includes a variable `lkwid` and the getter and setter methodes.

Cargo .h

```
@interface Cargo : CDVPlugin {
    NSString *lkwid;    
}

//@property (retain, getter=lkwid) NSString *lkwid;

-(NSString*) lkwid;
-(void)setLKW:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;
-(void) setlkwid:(NSString *)textValue;

@end
```

Cargo .m

```
#import "Cargo.h"

@implementation Cargo

-(void) setLKW:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options {
    NSString* callbackId = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];
    lkwid = callbackId;
    NSLog(@"LKW übergeben %@ ",lkwid);
}

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // initialize stuff here
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) setlkwid:(NSString *)textValue
{
    if (textValue != lkwid)
    {
        [textValue retain];
        [lkwid release];
        lkwid = textValue;
    }
}

-(NSString*) lkwid
{
    return lkwid;
}
@end
```

Now I want to access to the variable lkwid from another class named MainViewController. I`ve imported Cargo.h to that class and created an object *car in the MainViewController.h

```
@interface MainViewController : CDVViewController <CoreLocationControllerDelegate> {
    Cargo *car;
}

    @property (nonatomic, retain) Cargo *car;
```

In the MainViewController.h I want to access to lkwid from the Cargo class but that returns always (null). 
For example. Even when I set lkwid to a value, the class returns null.

```
[car setlkwid:@"ABC"];
NSLog(@"%@ ",[car lkwid]);
```

Do you have a tip whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you ever initialize the car object. It looks like you declared it and then did not construct it, so it returned nil for every value.